# Retrieving header value in the api route file is not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, http-headers

I am developing a Web Api using Laravel. In the routes/api.php file, I am trying to retrieve the header value. But it is throwing the error.

First I retrieve like this.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Request::header('api-version')
```

But, the error is saying that the method should not be called statically.

Then I used this one.

```
use Request;

    Request::header('api-version')
```

When I tried the second one, it gave me this error.

```
The use statement with non-compound name 'Request' has no effect
```

So, how can I retrieve header value inside api route file in Laravel?

Comment: Please show your route.

Comment: I did nothing. I just did a if statement. That is it.